# Wrap CLI tool around interactive CLI (mysql) process

Tags: process, command-line-interface

I've made a simple CLI tool to manage mysql privileges. It's written in PHP, and uses a PHP lib to talk to mysql. The first thing the tool needs, is mysql credentials, because the PHP lib needs those to talk to the mysql daemon (probably on the same server). That works, BUT

I need it to work without credentials. On some servers, I can only run mysql with `sudo mysql` and then be logged in as mysql root. That's fine too, but my tool can't use that.

Can I wrap my tool around the mysql client, instead of initiating a mysql client inside the tool?

If I can do that, the tool works with any auth method:

- `sudo mysql | tool`
- `mysql --login-path=~/.mysql-creds | tool`
- `mysql -ufoo -pbar | tool`
- `mysql -hdb.server.com -upublic | tool`

But how? How do I get the tool talking to the process around/outside it?

I could use PHP's `proc` functions to init the process in PHP and read/write from there, but I'm interested in any tool around any process, without knowing the process' name/location. (The tool shouldn't have to know `mysql -ufoo -pbar` or `sudo mysql`.)

These don't work:

- `mysql | tool`
- `mysql < tool`
- `tool < mysql`

Or without PHP. How would Python do this? Or even Bash?